# How to Get DB Field name from ConstraintViolationException - Hibernamte

Tags: java, hibernate

How to get the Name of the DB field causing ConstraintViolationException  while inserting in to Database in hibernate.

I have the Table Like

```
mysql> desc Mytable;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | bigint(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(20) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| city  | varchar(20) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And records inthe table are

```
mysql> select * from Mytable;
+----+--------+-------+
| id | name   | city  |
+----+--------+-------+
|  1 | SATISH | BLORE |
+----+--------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, im trying to insert

`"RAMESH","BLORE" through hibernate`.

It is throwing `ConstraintViolationException due to "BLORE" (CITY) already Exist`.

if im trying to insert.

```
"SATISH","MLORE" through hibernate
```

It is throwing `ConstraintViolationException due to "SATISH" (NAME) already Exist`.

My question is 
how to get fieldName who is causing the exception ConstraintViolationException through Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Since there might be other constraints that could be violated (e.g. combined keys), you only have the name of the constraint that is violated, which in your case might just be the column name (however, I'm not entirely sure about that). You can get the name of the violated constraint by calling `getConstraintName()` on the `ConstraintViolationException`.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I tried with getConstraintName() method it is giving NULL.

Comment: @sateesh Hmm, that could be a problem of the MySQL dialect. AFAIK `MySQLDialect` doesn't override the `getViolatedConstraintNameExtracter()` method and thus returns an extractor that always gives `null` as the constraint name which is then passed to the exception. In that case it seems like you'd have to manually get the constraint name from the nested `SQLException`.