# Get data which violate DB constraint

Tags: java, exception, constraints

I am trying to import data from XML and insert it into a database. Now if there is any data which violates a constraint, I want to show it to the user because there are hundreds of rows getting inserted from the XML.

Is there any way to know which data cause this `ConstraintViolationException`?

I have gone through a the SO post [How To Get DB Field Name From ConstraintViolationException in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160928/how-to-get-db-field-name-from-constraintviolationexception-hibernamte), but the suggested answer in the post only gives me which constraint was violated, and not the data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had the same question few days ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246433/how-to-know-which-entity-caused-sql-exception (no solution yet)

Comment: are you using any framework like spring or hibernate?

Comment: Yes. Using Hibernate. after starting transaction I started saving records like hSession.save(object), and finaly when I say transaction.commit(), this exception throws.

Comment: Try to insert each single row in a `try/catch` block. The try block should have a `flush` after `persist`. The `catch` has access to the single row.

Comment: Thanks Michael... But this is just a work around :(